# echonest query json parsing with php

Tags: php, json, echonest

I'm trying to parse this echonest request:

`{"response": {"status": {"version": "4.2", "code": 0, "message": "Success"}, "start": 0, "total": 1, "biographies": [{"text": "Pianist, composer and leader (8 September 1893 - 25 January 1947) Complete name: Adolfo Carabelli", "site": "last.fm", "url": "http://www.last.fm/music/Adolfo+Carabelli/+wiki", "license": {"type": "cc-by-sa", "url": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/", "version": "3.0"}}]}}`

My code:

```
$biographie = $jbios->response->biographies[1]->text;
echo "<b> Biographie: </b>". $biographie."<br>";
```

What's wrong ?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: you only have one `biographies` entry in there, therefore it'd be `biographies[0]`. A simple `var_dump($jbios)` would have shown you this.

Comment: Did you do a json_decode first?

Comment: Was there a reported error?

Comment: @fluinc yes, json decode was put first.

Comment: @Greg the log says: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @Marc B you were right, It was just a mistake with the number of index. Greg after to rewrite my code i was notice that json_decode was put in a variable in order to perform my debug, that's way the error message.  Thanks Guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you did json_decode?
Please try:

```
$array = json_decode($json,true)
```